# Search a file with a zimage file extension in Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am writing a program to upgrade a firmware using a flash drive. I need to upgrade the Kernel with the image present in the flash device. But I am not getting any idea of how to find a file with zimage file extension in a directory.
I am new to Qt and Linux. So I dont know whether it is possible to find the file with particular format. Can anyone help on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute next script using [system()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system), and parse the output :

```
#!/bin/bash

find / -name '*.zimage' | grep .zimage > /tmp/zimage_files.txt
```

Take a note that the above script is going to search all files and all paths, and put the output to `/tmp/zimage_files.txt`. If you need something different, you need to modify it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

There's no general way to access the OS search indexing services on the whole filesystem in Qt.  So if that's what you want then an OS-specific solution like what @BЈовић offered would be necessary.

*(Note: I actually tend to prefer it when a program makes me point explicitly to where something is, instead of searching the whole filesystem...but even better if it can notice when the necessary file is in the same directory as the executable.)*

Anyway...if you know the directory you want to search in, then the [QDir](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdir.html) abstraction will let you set up a filter and enumerate filenames that match that filter in the directory:

```
QDir dir (zimagePath);
QStringList filters;
filters << "*.zimage";

foreach (QString file, dir.entryList(filters, QDir::Files)) {
    // ...
}
```

You can read over the QDir docs for more ways of looking at it.